# OOP-php - Can not retrive data from database

Tags: php, oop

I'm a new with OOP model in PHP. I has been trying to retrieve data from  database but something related to private makes me stuck.
This is my code.

```
<?php 

require ("UserData.php");

class Database{

    public function getUser($sql){

    include ("includes/connect.php");
        $statement = $conn->prepare ($sql);
        $statement->execute();

        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {

            $dataSet[] = new UserData($row);
        }

        if (!empty($dataSet)) {
            return $dataSet;

        }else{
            die();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

the second file

```
<?php 

class UserData
{
    private $user_id, $phone,$name,$address;

    public function _construct($dbrow){ 

        $this->user_id = $dbrow['user_id'];
        $this->name = $dbrow['name'];
        $this->phone = $dbrow['phone'];
        $this->address = $dbrow['address'];
    }
    public function getUserId(){
        return $this->user_id;
    }
    public function getUserName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getUserPhone(){
        return $this->phone;
    }
    public function getUserAddress(){
        return $this->address;
    }
}
?>
```

and the last one

```
<?php require ("Database.php"); ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>OOP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    include("includes/connect.php");

    $db = new Database();

    $dataSet = $db -> getUser ("SELECT * from user");


    if ($dataSet) {

        foreach ($dataSet as $data) {   
            echo "<p>";
            echo "ID" .$data->getUserId()."<br />";
            echo "Name" .$data->getUserName()."<br />";
            echo "Phone" .$data->getUserPhone()."<br />";
            echo "Address" .$data->getUserAddress()."<br />";
            echo "</p>";
        }

    }else{
        echo "no result found";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Well, I tried to `var_dump` the `dataSet` but the error shows up.

> array(2) { [0]=> object(UserData)#5 (4) {
>   ["user_id":"UserData":private]=> NULL ["phone":"UserData":private]=>
>   NULL ["name":"UserData":private]=> NULL
>   ["address":"UserData":private]=> NULL } [1]=> object(UserData)#6 (4) {
>   ["user_id":"UserData":private]=> NULL ["phone":"UserData":private]=>
>   NULL ["name":"UserData":private]=> NULL
>   ["address":"UserData":private]=> NULL } }

So can anyone show me which spots make the code dump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is okay except this line,

```
public function _construct($dbrow){ ...
                ^^^^^^^^^^ it should be double underscore, not single
```

Your constructor method in `UserData` class is wrong. It should be,

```
public function __construct($dbrow){ ...
```

Comment: damn, u save my night dude!!!! i'll click the tick when i am allowed!!!

Comment: @vinataba Glad I could help. *Cheers! :-)*

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.6.0+, you can use the magic mathod __debugInfo()

```
class UserData
{
    public function __debugInfo() {
        return ['user_id' => $this->user_id, 'phone' => $this->phone, 'name' => $this->name, 'address' => $this->address];
    }
}
```

or makes variables public, which is not intend when you have methods like `getUserId`

or create method to dump like:

```
class UserData
{
    public function dump() {
        var_dump($this);
    }
}
```

btw in class `Database` method `getUser` you include all the time when method is called, quick fix: use `require_once` instead of `include`, better will be to call `include`/`require`/`require_once` outside of class